# Data down binding for child components in Emblem.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, components, parent-child, emblem.js

Environment, Ember w/ Emblem.js

Working on a project, and I'm trying to make it modular to dynamically pull in the correct form layout (child component) depending on what choice the user makes.

Problem I'm having is I have a child component with references to mutable objects in the parent that I am trying to access for read, and write.

I believe that I need to bind the data down, then push the mut action back up to the parent based on DDAU.

**JS**
**Parent.js**

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
store: Ember.inject.service(),
name: null,
infoArray: Ember.computed.map(....),
isVisibleChild1: false;
actions: {
    picker() {
        if(dropdown.value==1)
            this.set('isVisibleChild1', true);
    }
},
```

**Child1.js**

```
needs to contain a variable childInfoArray somewhere
```

I found online that to bind data from parent to child forms with hbs

```
{{Child1 childInfoArray=infoArray}}
```

but I'm using Emblem.js instead of hbs

**Emblem.js**
**Parent.emblem**

```
if isVisibleChild1
    = Child1
    childInfoArray = infoArray
```

**Child1.emblem**
I recognize that infoArray should probably be childInfoArray

```
select id="newInfo" onchange={action (mut infoArray) value="target.value"}
    each optionsArray as |selectOption|
        option selected={is-equal selectOption.key infoArray} value="#{selectOption.key}" = selectOption.value
```

I'm not sure where exactly the childInfoArray should go in Child1.js and I'm not totally sure how to bind it to an object in Child1.emblem

any help would be fantastic!

Interesting side note, I have several text entry fields and date-time pickers.

The date-time pickers get picked up by the parent component when saving the data to the database, but the entry fields say that there is no object bound to them.

Comment: I know this may be inappropriate, I understand It's not always as simple as that (project already existing etc ...); But if it's a new one and you have liberty on what you can do, can I advise you to switch for mustaches ? The community is much bigger and it will be easier for you to get answers. I have to say I am good with emberjs, but I can't help you on this. Cheers

Comment: I wish that I could just use the tools with more support, but as you said, existing project, I can't just start from scratch.

Comment: Yup ... what about the solution below ?

Comment: I posted the solution I found in the answers section. Thanks!

Comment: mhm ... the solution is all about the var naming ... nothing to do with handlebar or not but .. anyway. Glad my answer helped you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, using the = I can send any classic handlebar through Emblem, the solution was way more simple than I thought

Child1.js

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    infoArray:null,
}
```

Parent.emblem

```
if isVisibleChild1
    = Child1 infoArray=infoArray
```

Child1.emblem

```
select id="newInfo" onchange={action (mut infoArray) value="target.value"}
```

I can bind everything in this way

```
= Child1 infoArray=infoArray property2=property2 myFunction=myFunction
```

Comment: the problem was here : `= Child1 childInfoArray = infoArray`. Now you changed it to `= Child1 infoArray=infoArray`. You can bind whatever you want with whatever you need. Keep in mind that when you call your child component, the var name at the left is the way you can access it in your child, and the var_name at the right is the parent var_name containing the value you want to pass : `= Child1 pp1=pp2` works. It's just that now you can access, from the child, the value of parent `pp2` with `pp1`

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is that you don't have access to `infoArray` in your Child1.emblem file. You bind the parent `infoArray` on `childInfoArray`. So 2 choices.

**Or** you change the name of your binding key `childInfoArray` to `infoArray` into Parent.emblem :

```
if isVisibleChild1
    = Child1
    infoArray = infoArray
```

**Or** you use the appropriate key into Child1.emblem :

```
select id="newInfo" onchange={action (mut childInfoArray) value="target.value"}
```

Does it helps ?